# Loading other html file within a div doesn't use the CSS of current file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a code like this:

```
  <div class="bg-faded text-center p-1 h-50" id="content">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row py-4 my-2">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3 class="">Simplicity</h3>
      <p class="lead">Just set the bot up and run it, the rest will be done for you!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3 class="">No risk of ban</h3>
      <p class="lead">The bot doesn't use any kind of injection, thus the chances of getting banned are almost non-existent!<br></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3 class="">Time</h3>
      <p class="lead">A single bot takes about a week to get the account to level 30!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3 class="">Limitless</h3>
      <p class="lead">You can run as many bots as you want!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3 class="">Performance</h3>
      <p class="lead">The bot itself uses about 20 MB RAM, so it doesn't overload your computer!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3 class="">Updates</h3>
      <p class="lead">The application is gets constantly updated, thus works with the latest patches!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3 class="">Resolutions</h3>
      <p class="lead">It works on every single resolution higher than 1024x546!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3 class="">Regions support</h3>
      <p class="lead">It supports every single region, all you need to do is changing the language to English!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center text-uppercase" data-toggle="">Purchase now!</a></div>
  </div>
```

'

and it works properly, but when I load other html file in the "content", the file doesn't use the css etc. included in index.html

Here's the including code:

```
  <script>
  function load_purchase() {
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="purchase.html" ></object>';
    }
  </script>
```

and this is the "purchase.html":

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center text-uppercase" data-toggle="">Test</a></div>
  </div>
```

It doesn't use the css file, so it's just showing text "Test" without any styles.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`object`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element) elements are like `iframes`, they don't inherit styling or similar from their parent.

If you want `purchase.html` to be *part* of the document, including being styled by its stylesheets, etc., you'll want to load it via ajax and then assign the HTML directly to `innerHTML` on `#content`.

E.g., roughly:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", "purchase.html");
```

Apologies, since you weren't using jQuery in your code, I didn't realize you were using jQuery until I saw the tag later. jQuery has a [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function for this, as [called out by Super User](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846098/157247):

```
$("#content").load("purchase.html");
```

Comment: yeah I tried using the jquery load but it wouldn't work at all I have no idea why

Comment: @PSawicki: Well, you don't have to use jQuery if this is your only reason for using it, see my first codeblock for (roughly) the same thing using the DOM directly.

Comment: Thank you for the code, but I'd like to use jQuery as it looks much simplier.
However, it doesn't work, do you have any idea why?
Here's the code: 
https://pastebin.com/jN35eWud

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @PSawicki: Yes: You have invisible characters in your jquery path (in the `jquery.min.js` part, delete all of it and type it back in again). Look in your web console, the errors will show up. (The web console is the **first** place to look when things don't work.) If you fix the path, that code works.

Comment: What is the web console?

Comment: @PSawicki: I suggest a search on the term. Also "developer tools." Glad that worked!

Comment: How could I make it that when you open the website, it loads "home.html" automatically?

Comment: @PSawicki: Just put a `load`call in your script at the end not inside any function, and it'll get run when the script is run. I suggest playing around with things, running through some tutorials, etc. You'll soon get the hang of it. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `object` you can use jQuery `.load()` function

```
$("#content").load("purchase.html");
```

For detail you can check [jquery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: i tried using it but for some reason I couldn't get it working at all.

Comment: @P Sawicki if you are not using `jQuery` then remove `jQuery` tag from your question, we are giving you the right solution.
Please include `jQuery` library first then use this code. it will definitely work.

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>

Comment: Should I put it on <head>?

Comment: @PSawicki: You don't **have** to use jQuery for this (see my answer). But if you want to, please work through some basic jQuery tutorials.

Comment: you have to include `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: I've got this in <head>:
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min‌​.js"></script>

and this on the bottom of the page
  <script>
  function load_purchase() {
     $("#content").load("purchase.html");
 }
  </script>

and it doesn't  work at all, nothing changes

Comment: check your developer option for any error, i think you have written wrong path for jquery it should be `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min‌​‌​.js">`

Comment: @SuperUser: The path in the comment is right, it's just that it's not marked up correctly.

Comment: I've put your link but it just doesn't change anything, it just doesn't work. I tried using copy/paste links from people for whom it worked and it didn't either.

Comment: @SuperUser do you know what might be wrong in there?